# how to create more no of controls dynamically to wxscrolledwindow in c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a list containing a number of different controls (wxStaticText, wxTextCtrl, wxCheckBox, wxRadioButton, wxComboBox, wxListButton). I'm currently creating a large number of controls dynamically in my wxScrolledWindow. When I create more than 5,000 controls this way, my EXE hangs if I scroll the window.

I want to fix this problem by only creating the objects shown on-screen, and dynamically creating/destroying objects as I scroll my window. How do I implement this?

Comment: I suspect you'll have that problem regardless of how you create those controls. 5000 is quite a lot, and they'll consume a good bit of both memory and processing time. You may want to consider whether you really need that many controls in a single window.

Comment: I want that many controls in my scrolled window .I want to fix this problem by only creating the objects shown on-screen, and dynamically creating/destroying objects as I scroll my window. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create that many controls. There is a limit of 10000 windows under Windows and while it can be increased, it's really not a wise thing to do.

Creating the controls on demand when they're scrolled into view risks being tricky. Instead, consider using [wxGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html) or [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) to display your data and create the controls only for the (single) item being currently edited.